# Webserver running out of memory because of too many php5-cgi processes

Tags: php, apache, ram

I have a webserver where, once in a while, a process is killed because the server runs out of memory.
Thanks to dmesg I can see there are too many php5-cgi processes eating all my RAM.
Most of the time there are about 4 or 5 php5-cgi processes, but when the OOM killer is called I can see 30 to 40.
I have pm.max_children = 5, but it does not limit the number of php5-cgi processes.
What's the best way to solve this and avoid the call of the OOM killer ?
I am running Debian 3.16.39-1, Apache/2.4.10, PHP Version 5.6.30
I use php-fpm

Thanks.

Comment: is it possible to describe your webserver setup?

Comment: I just updated my question with my webserver setup

Comment: adjust your max_children setting, see https://myshell.co.uk/blog/2012/07/adjusting-child-processes-for-php-fpm-nginx/

Comment: max_children is not available under apache with cgi. do you use fastcgi or what?

Comment: Does this happen because the amount of visitors you receive, or just a single PHP script hogging resources?

Comment: It happens when there is a temporary peak of visitor.
I have cgi and fastcgi apache2 modules enabled

Comment: I updated my post : the pm.max_children = 5 does not limit the number of php5-cgi processes, so I don't know how to do it.